# Which thread in my managed app caused the crash?

Tags: .net, debugging, windbg

My windbg skills are a little rusty, so forgive me if this is obvious.

3 threads have exceptions against them.  Does this mean they are at the top of the stack on each thread?  I don't understand how that can occur, because the first of them would cause the unhandled exception handler to kick in and crash my app.  Abbreviated output below.

```
!threads

   0    1 1e5c 0015c008   2006020 Enabled  00000000:00000000 0015a4a8     6 STA
   2    2 2734 00176740      b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 0015a4a8     0 MTA (Finalizer)
   4    3 1f64 001b22d0   880b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 0015a4a8     0 MTA 
  25   14 2714 0897ef78   180b220 Enabled  39e4bf38:39e4cbec 0015a4a8     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  29   19 1884 0898a3b8  1000b221 Disabled 39f36d50:39f38bec 0015a4a8     0 MTA System.Threading.ThreadAbortException (39f36bf8)
  71   57 164c 274b41f0      b220 Enabled  39ef4098:39ef4bec 0015a4a8     4 MTA System.NullReferenceException (39ef3028)
  72   58 223c 274b1110   200b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 0015a4a8     0 MTA
 107   83 1e60 275fe008      b020 Enabled  00000000:00000000 0015a4a8     0 MTA System.ObjectDisposedException (1e66684c)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it seems there's no way to tell for sure which thread caused the debugger to invoke.

Answer (score 3):

The `!threads` command outputs the last exception per thread. Since all the threads could have exceptions happening at the same time you can see more than one exception, but it isn't very common in my experience.

However, I do notice that the output lists a thread id of 107, so I assume that the application creates a lot of threads. I also notice that some of the threads are holding multiple locks. Perhaps one or more of the threads are blocked in a state where the exception is still present on the stack.

It's hard to say anything more specific with the information at hand.

Answer (score 2):

You can set which exceptions you want WinDbg to break on under Debug->Event Filters. I've not done .net debugging using WinDbg but I have previously used these event filters to trap a particular handled exception to get the call stack of the offending code.

It is quite normal for many handled exceptions to occur of course so I don't know what your app state really means but you should be able to either switch threads and dump the call stack and inspect the exception context record or to set whether you want WinDbg to break on these exceptions occurring and then when they do occur compare the call stacks, hit go and see if it crashes by enabling/disabling them as a process of elimination.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This is actually a crash dump from a user's machine of a hard to repro issue, so the exception has already happened.  Just trying to figure out which thread it was that caused the crash!

Comment: You should still be able to go through each thread, dump the call stack and inspect the registers and if an exception was thrown the exception context but this may be hard given it is a 3rd party dump

Answer (score 1):

Usually if you open a crash dump in windbg, it will give the exception that caused the crash
as soon as the crash dump is loaded. You should see a message in windbg similar to this

*"This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(1890.da0): Stack overflow - code c00000fd (first/second chance not available)"*

And the thread that caused the exception should be same as the thread number you see in the
bottom left corner of windbg once you load the crash dump.

Comment: Thanks.  Mine says: 
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(1ecc.1e5c): Wake debugger - code 80000007
which isn't terribly useful!